# Stored Procedure gives Cannot find object... error in SSIS, but works fine in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am trying to build an SSIS package that dynamically rebuilds the indexes for all the tables in my database. The general idea is that the package will make sure that the table is not being update and then execute a stored procedure that drops the old index, if it exists, and then recreates it. The logic behind the package seems to be sound. The problem that I am having is when I execute the package I keep getting the error:

> Cannot find object...because it does not exist or you do not have permission...

The index existing should be irrelevant due to the `IF EXISTS` part.

The procedure looks like this:

```
REFERENCE_NAME AS VARCHAR(50), 
COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(50),
INDEX_NAME AS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes WHERE name = '+CHAR(39)+@INDEX_NAME+CHAR(39)+') '+
           'DROP INDEX '+@INDEX_NAME+' ON '+@REFERENCE_NAME+' '+

           'CREATE INDEX '+@INDEX_NAME+' ON '+@REFERENCE_NAME+'('+@COLUMN_NAME+') ON [INDEX]'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END

GO
```

I am able to execute the procedure through SSMS just fine, no error and it builds the index. When I execute the package in SSIS it errors out the minute it gets to the task that executes the stored procedure. I have made sure that SSIS is passing the variables to the execute SQL task and I have verified that I have db_ddladmin rights. Outside of that I am at a loss and have been beating my head against the wall for a day and a half on this.

Is there something I am missing, some permissions I need to request, or some work around for the issue?

Any information would be much appreciated.

---

Bartover, its definitely not looking at the wrong database. I have checked that the proc is there and the only connection on the package is to that specific database. Yes, I am executing the package manually with Visual Studios 2010 Shell Data Tools. 
Sorrel, I tried your idea of a sanity check on the @sql statement on the drop, on both the drop and create, and on whole @sql statement, no joy. 
Gnackenson, I had that same thought, but the connection authentication method is set to Windows Authentication, same as ssms. Do you have any ideas as to why it might use different permissions?

Comment: Can you determine if that's actually an error from within the procedure or SSIS error indicating that it doesn't see the proc (maybe wrong database)? How are you executing the package? Manually through Data Tools?

Comment: Have you tried a sanity check of adding BEGIN/END in your @sql statement?
`'BEGIN DROP INDEX '+@INDEX_NAME+' ON '+@REFERENCE_NAME+' END '+...`

Comment: When you run the SSIS package , are you sure it's running under the same permissions as it was in ssms

Comment: Bartover, its definitely not looking at the wrong database. I have checked and double checked that the proc is in fact there and the only connection I have on the SSIS package is to that specific database. Yes, I am executing the SSIS package manually with Visual Studios 2010 Shell Data Tools.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `IF EXISTS` is being ignored by SSIS SQL Task. To fix my problem, I altered my SQL tasks from `DROP - CREATE` to `DISABLE - ENABLE`.